# Changing field in Gravity form to a drop down list

Tags: php, html, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Ok so...i have a form that allows users to fill out specific stuff like address and what not. Recently i wanted to change the "state" field to a drop downlist of the states in the us rather than having it as a field you can type into.

Here is what i have now....

```
<div class="atl_form_row">
    <div class="atl_left"><span class="mandatory"></span><label class="control-label atlFormLabel" for="Service State">Service State:</label></div>
    <div class="atl_right">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Service  State:" id="ServiceState" name="ServiceState" class="service_request_txt" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried making it into something like this but does not work unfortunately...

```
<div class="atl_form_row">
    <div class="atl_left"><span class="mandatory"></span><label class="control-label atlFormLabel" for="Service State">Service State:</label></div>
    <div class="atl_right">
        <select id="GISState" name="GISState">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select State</option>
            <option value="AL">AL</option>
            <!-- more options here -->
            <option value="WY">WY</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Define "Doesn't Work?"

Comment: Specifically what does not work? Does the dropdown not show up on the page? Is Gravity Forms not recording the chosen result? Something else?

Comment: nothing seems to be happening to the field...the state values dont come out on the drop down. im wondering if i added the state values wrong?

Comment: use chosen jQuery plugin. easy to use. http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Why are you changing HTML when you are using GravityForms?